# Some umlauts and extended Latin characters are shown as fullwidth

Tags: macvim, unicode, macos, font, iterm2

In Vim, I find each of `ü` and `ß` takes up fullwidth, i.e. twice as fat as ASCII characters. 
I am writing some German-learning notes, and find this to be very confusing, since I have been mistaken that there were a whitespace following that character.
How can I make them shown as halfwidth?

Afterwards, out of curiosity, I tried some extended Latin characters (umlauts, accented vowels, currency symbols, etc.), and find some other characters looking like halfwidth but be shown as fullwidth. They include (but I suppose are not restricted to)

```
ßüŒœø€§¶
```

This is true for Vim inside iTerm2, MacVim inside iTerm2, Vim inside Terminal.app, MacVim inside Terminal.app, and even for standalone GUI of MacVim. I have tried several monospace fonts, including Monaco and Menlo. I use Mac Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it's because I set `:set ambiwidth=double`. It makes some characters twice as wide as usual. I set `:set ambiwidth=single`, and all is fine. This line, I must have copied from some stranger's vimrc and did not examine closely. It's my fault, not Vim's fault.

I have no idea what `ambiwidth` is for. Maybe there is some font that need it to display right (see `:help 'ambiwidth'`). But as I cancelled it and set to `single`, everything still seems fine, Chinese or English. This question is kept for future reader's convenience.

Comment: There are a lot of options in Vim and identifying which one is wrongly configured can take some time. In case it helps, you can use the `:option` command to narrow down your search. The window displayed by this command is divided into sections. Each section regroups some options around a common theme. For example, it seems the `'ambiwidth'` option is inside the `multi-byte characters` section. In this window, you can play with the settings of the options, with a few keys which are described at the top.